# A word or phrase to be used as a seasonal enantiomer, a Winter equivalent for 'The garden of Eden'

Tags: phrase-requests

A dozen miles up the Chilkat River near the village of Klukwan AK (in The Chilkat Bald Eagle Preserve) is a short stretch of river where thousands of Bald Eagles overwinter (known as The Council of Eagles). A population of Chum salmon spawns at this location.  Incredibly, salmon numbers peak in the middle of December! There is a geological reason why this section never freezes. Huge #'s of Salmon swim to the Bald Eagles and spawn out in shallow 'refrigerated'water.  A Garden of Eden. But it’s not, it's dark, overcast freezing, snowing. These airborne predators become terrestrial scavengers. Different sides of the same coin? 2 peas in a pod?

Comment: It's the eagles who have come to the salmon. The salmon have not come to the eagles, but to the spawning pool. The eagles have nothing to offer the salmon, so there is no symbiosis.

Comment: No harm in suggesting a similarity between this winter wonderland and the Garden of Eden. If there are two sides to the coin, I don't see it. Two peas in a pod, definitely not. "Huge #'s of Salmon" is usually written as *Huge numbers of salmon.*

Comment: It is a **haven** for both parties, almost **heaven**.